# Can't read tc Server property [PropertyDecoder] due to a NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tcserver

My workmate and I are on the same environments:

- Spring Tool Suite 2.9.2 (Eclipse 3.7.2)
- Java 6 update 43
- VMware vFabric tc Server v2.5, v2.6, v.27 (tomcat-7.0.20.B.RELEASE)

My server has no problems when starting;  however, his server has the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to load property source[com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder].
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at com.springsource.tcserver.security.KeyDecoder.initCiphers(KeyDecoder.java:68)
    at com.springsource.tcserver.security.KeyDecoder.<init>(KeyDecoder.java:48)
    at com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder.<init>(PropertyDecoder.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit>(Digester.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was causing this, but upgrading to `Java 7 Update 17` fixed it.